# subreport in Detail band getting displayed repeatedly

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a subreport included in the Detail band of the parent report. The SQL query in the parent report returns multiple rows. And so my subreport also gets displayed as many times as the records returned by parent SQL query. I want to display subreport only once irrespective of the records returned by SQL query in parent report. I have tried moving subreport to columnfooter section but then i get a "Subreport overflowed on a band that does not support overflow" error. 
Any pointers to get it working will be really helpful.

Comment: Please post jrxml files for parent report and subreport.

Answer (score 1):

Ok to start with: a subreport has a different Dataset (SQL query) then the parent report. If you use an query, the subreport is shown as many times as there are records as a result of the query. This is actually what it's meant for and that's the same as with parent reports.

What you want to achieve if I unerstand you correctly, is that you have the supreport outputted once and the main report outputted as many times as there are records returned. What I would suggest is:

- Why don't you turn it around? Would solve all your problems and you use the programm as how it's meant to. You can do it like this:

  - Put the query that returns mulptiple record in a subreport, change layout so it matches your current parent report.
  - Put the data that should be displayed only once in you parent report Query (LIMIT bij 1 if it can return multiple records but you need the first). And put the necessary textfields etc. in the main report before or after the subreport.

Hope it helps! Let me know